# Cannot delete Realm User

Tags: realm, realm-java

I login to Realm by SyncCredentials allow create User as code below:

```
SyncCredentials credentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username, password, true);
SyncUser.logInAsync(credentials, AUTH_URL, new SyncUser.Callback<SyncUser>() {
}
```

And after I want to delete this User on Realm with code below:

```
String id = SyncUser.current().getIdentity();
PermissionUser permissionUser = realm.where(PermissionUser.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
if (permissionUser != null) {
    permissionUser.getPrivateRole().removeMember(id);
    permissionUser.getPrivateRole().deleteFromRealm();
    if (permissionUser.getRoles() != null) {
        permissionUser.getRoles().deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
    permissionUser.deleteFromRealm();
}
```

This code run successfully but I have checked on Realm Studio, this User still existed.
Please help me this problem, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**All changes to data must happen in a transaction**

source: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

example:

```
// obtain the results of a query
final RealmResults<Dog> results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
@Override
public void execute(Realm realm) {
    // remove single match
    results.deleteFirstFromRealm();
    results.deleteLastFromRealm();

    // remove a single object
    Dog dog = results.get(5);
    dog.deleteFromRealm();

    // Delete all matches
    results.deleteAllFromRealm();
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PrisonMike but I think I have answer for this.

Comment: I don't see why or how your answer solves the issue. I thought the problem was that you could not delete your realm user? this doesn't have anything to do with OkHttp

Answer (score 0):

Thaank you for everyone but I hanve found the solution here:

```
String url = RealmConstants.AUTH_URL + "/user/" + SyncUser.current().getIdentity();
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = RetrofitClient.ClientHolder.getOkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .addHeader("Authorization", token.value())
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*")
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .delete()
                .build();
okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
        callback.onFailure(new ClientError(e.hashCode(), e.getMessage()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) {
        callback.onSuccess(null);
    }
});
```